How to calculate Vout/Vin for the given circuit?
Is it standard to use mesh or nodal analysis for this problem?

Edit: This is a phasor problem.

What have you been recently studying? It would seem that the appropriate tool to use would be the one being taught, at the time, for the context of this circuit. So what's the context? And what do you think?

I provide a SymPy program to create a transfer function from a netlist in this answer. This means you can just pop your schematic into a capture program, get it to generate the netlist for you, copy it as text, and just paste it into the software. It will generate $H_s=\frac{V_{\text{OUT}}}{V{\text{IN}}}$. Since $I{\text{IN}}=\frac{V{\text{IN}}}{Z}$, it follows that $\frac{V{\text{OUT}}}{I{\text{IN}}}=Z\cdot H_s$. *(You should be able to work out $V{_\text{IN}}$'s load, $Z$.)*

so I am calculating it. The answer is so long and tedious. is it supposed to be?

You didn't post the fuller context of the problem. But going on what you wrote, sure. It's not short.

Neither of them has been declared to be the standard. In schools the teacher may declare that only a certain method is allowed to get points from a problem in an exam, but both methods can be used if only the result is wanted.
Nodal method is a little more straightforward because you can write directly equations which have node voltages as unknown variables. Or actually V1 is known but one of the currents which enter to the leftmost node is Iin. You can solve from them the ratio Vout/Iin. The current loop method gives currents but it's not a big deal to present voltage Yout with the current of the rightmost branch.
After some practicing one can as well write the current loop equations by having there the needed voltages as variables.
Computer programs probably are preferably constructed to use nodal analysis because the circuits are generally presented there as connection lists between the nodes. Finding the loops is an extra task. A human sees them easily, but only if the circuit is simple enough.

i could calculate the Thevenin equivalent and make it one big giant impedance and V1/Zin as the Iin. Then find the voltage at vout by first finding the voltage at the top of L3 and using voltage division right?

I cannot see HOW you calculated the thevvenin equivalent and what's the used output port and how the Thevenin equivalent exactly is used. It's in theory possible that you have got the right result but only a competent clairvoyant could see if your  calculations actually are right. Thevenin equivalent doesn't reduce the number of needed calculation steps when you do not have  optional parts to be connected in parallel with C2 or replacing C2. The whole case could be solved as a big voltage division chain without taking mr. Thevenin to the game at all.

i didn't expect this problem to be this long. like with resistors, you reduce the network easily. tedious..

There is no "standard". (Except for the fact that mesh analysis can only be used for planar circuits, so if a circuit is not planar it is right out).
Best to look at the circuit and think before starting to write equations. In this circuit C1 doesn't matter. If it were me I might find a thevenin equivalent at the terminals of L3 and then do voltage division. If the node voltage method is used (and elements are combined to single impedances) then it is a single-node circuit, followed by voltage division to find vout.
OP hasn't said whether this is a transient or sinusoidal steady state problem.

steady state problem
